# Looping a function through Pandas dataframe with iterrows

Tags: python, pandas

My goal here is to transform the data in one dataframe and output the results to a new dataframe. Here's what I have so far, using a simplified dataframe:

```
import math
import pandas as pd
data = {'A':[1,4,3,5,7],'B':[0,6,3,0,2],'C':[1,1,3,0,4]} #sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
transDF = pd.DataFrame() #empty dataframe for results

def Chord(y): #Chord transformation function
    ySUM = sum(a*a for a in y)
    ySUMsqrt = math.sqrt(ySUM)
    yPRIME = []
    for a in y:
        RESULT = a/ySUMsqrt
        yPRIME.append(RESULT)
    return yPRIME

for Yi, row in df.iterrows(): #my attempt at a loop
    Yrow = df.loc[df.index == Yi]
    y = yRow.values.tolist()
    tfRow = float(Chord(y))
    transDF = transDF.append(tfRow)
```

The function itself works if I just feed it a list, but when I try the loop I get an error that says "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'". I've tried modifying my loop as many different ways as I can think of, but at this point I'm out of thoughts. I would greatly appreciate any insight!

Comment: The problem is that your function expects a list, not a list within a list, to simply fix your function change this line to `y = yRow.values.tolist()[0]` or you can change your function to take `x` amount of variables by doing this, `def Chord(*y)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, I don't think need iterrows for this problem.

```
import math
data = {'A':[1,4,3,5,7],'B':[0,6,3,0,2],'C':[1,1,3,0,4]} #sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
transDF = pd.DataFrame() #empty dataframe for results

def Chord(y): #Chord transformation function
    ySUM = sum(a*a for a in y)
    ySUMsqrt = math.sqrt(ySUM)
    yPRIME = []
    for a in y:
        RESULT = a/ySUMsqrt
        yPRIME.append(RESULT)
    return yPRIME

transDF = df.apply(Chord)
print(transDF)
```

Output:

```
     A         B        C
0  0.1  0.000000  0.19245
1  0.4  0.857143  0.19245
2  0.3  0.428571  0.57735
3  0.5  0.000000  0.00000
4  0.7  0.285714  0.76980
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is really inefficient.
Looping over rows in pandas is almost always unnecessary and looping over single elements should even more rare.

Make use of numpys vectorisation!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def chord_transform(row):
    return row / np.sum(row**2)

data = {'A':[1,4,3,5,7],'B':[0,6,3,0,2],'C':[1,1,3,0,4]} #sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_chord = df.apply(chord_transform, axis=1)
```

Comment: `.apply` *does* loop over the rows. Although, I agree, `np.sum(row**2)` is much preferable.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still new to python, so pretty much everything I write at this point is inefficient. :) I appreciate the input, and as the rest of the program I'm working on is similar in structure, this will definitely help!